# how to implement camera bottom navigation bar like whatsapp

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

how to implement camera tab in bottom navigation bar like Whatsapp :

[image]

**The main challenge here is to hide the bottom navigation bar and app bar and show them again, along with the ability to touch and move the view page.**

Comment: Add some code samples that you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this use, case use the PageView Widget.

Ref: https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-pageview-widget-e0f6c8092636

This should be like this below

```
PageView(
 controller: _controller,
 scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
 children: [
   CamerWidget(),
   HomeScreenWidget(),
   MyPage3Widget(),
 ],
)
```

Comment: Hi, the main challenge here is to hide the bottom navigation bar and app bar and show them again, along with the ability to touch and move the view page.

Comment: Try to Put the bottom nav bar inside the HomeScreenWidget